# FaceTime on an Iphone 6 bought in UAE

Tags: facetime

How can I make FaceTime appear in the iOS with an iPhone bought in UAE and used in another country?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't activate FaceTime service except by jailbreaking.

Answer (score 1):

iOS devices sold by the two local telecoms (DU and Etisalat) and on the local UAE online Apple store do not have facetime enabled on them unless you run the jailbroken, follow these instructions to activate FaceTime in any unsupported countries, including in the Middle East…

Step 1: Go to Cydia and add the following source: http://apps.iphoneislam.com

Step 2: Search for FaceTime Hacktivator. Install the app and reboot your iPhone.

Step 3: Go to Settings > Phone, and activate the FaceTime option.

Step 4: Your iPhone will then send the activation SMS.